# Convert a string of bytes into a python string

Tags: python, arrays, byte, ascii

I made an array of bytes like so:

```
import array
signal =  array.array('b', "bird")
print array
array('b', [98, 105, 114, 100])
```

I want to convert that back into `"bird"`.

How would I do that?

Comment: What is "bird text"?

Answer (score 0):

Join the ASCII-to-char array with `""` to create a string:

Python 2:

```
import array

signal = array.array('b', "bird")
print("".join(chr(x) for x in signal))
```

Python 3 (`bytes` needs encoding because it's now REAL binary):

```
import array

signal = array.array('b', bytes("bird","ascii"))
print("".join(chr(x) for x in signal)) # or print("".join(map(chr,signal)))
```